# Playing Ipywidgets Play widget by default and setting loop to true from the get-go

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm trying to create a Jupyter notebook which makes use of IPywidgets' Play widget (technically through NGLView). I was wondering if there is a way to set the Play widget to play by default and automatically loop whilst also permitting the user to pause the animation by clicking on the play button? I tried using IPython.display's Javascript class

```
 display(Javascript('''
    var playButton = document.querySelector('i.fa.fa-play');
    playButton.click();
'''))
```

,but never had any luck. Any advice would be much appreciated!